# ImageView not showing in android titanium

Tags: android, titanium-mobile

I have this code in my app.js file in android and an images folder in my resources:

```
var win = Titanium.UI.createWindow({

    title : "my Name is Reyjohn",
    backgroundColor : "#FFFFFF",

    exitOnClose : true

})


var img = Titanium.UI.createImageView({


    image:"images/Hypedin.png",
    height:20,
    width:30


});


win.add(img);

win.open();
```

but its not showing any image in background, where did I do wrong? I am new in titanium, please help

Comment: Did you try to replace image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing wrong with your code. Check and make sure that, `images/Hypedin.png` is there with correct spelling. Could be a typo.

Comment: I had to do this to make it working in tiapp.xml

<property name="ti.android.fastdev" type="bool">false</property>

Comment: this means that you have issue with emulator only. there was no error in the code and it would have run on actual device.

Comment: I am using titanium sdk 5. Image view work when i run with LiveView but not working without LiveView

Answer (score 6):

Try to add another / to the Path like:

```
image:"/images/Hypedin.png",
```

You can also try to set the correct Positioning:

```
top: 0,
left: 0
```

Did you check the Log/Output? Is there any Error?

Comment: My js file was in another folder, adding a slash at start fixed it. Thanks